# How to accept all the alerts of a website?

Tags: selenium, python-3.x

When browsing webpages, I get sometimes alerts. How can I accept each alert that appears ? I have no idea what is the number of alerts that are in a given webpage.

Comment: This is just a simple programming logic problem. A simple solution is to keep looping until WebDriver stops giving you alerts to accept. It's going to be slow since you've got no idea how many alerts are going to come up, and getting an alert using WebDriver can be expensive.

Comment: @Arran In which sens will it be expensive (**getting an alert using WebDriver can be expensive**). Is there a simpler way to browse a webpage and get its alerts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](http://htmlite.com/JS006.php) alerts, let us make a test:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common import alert
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
class AlertsManager:
    def alertsManager(self,url):
        self.url_to_visit=url
        self.driver=webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get(self.url_to_visit)
        try:
            while WebDriverWait(self.driver,1).until(EC.alert_is_present()):
                self.alert=self.driver.switch_to_alert()
                self.driver.switch_to_alert().accept()
        except TimeoutException:
            pass
        print("Continue what you want here ...")

if __name__=='__main__':
    AM=AlertsManager()
    url="http://htmlite.com/JS006.php"
    AM.alertsManager(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set capabilities. However the required capabilities may not be implemented on some specific browsers, test it by your self (As my knowledge, it only works with FF).

```
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR,UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.ACCEPT);
```